# exported runnable jar doesn't contain dependency jars from eclipse 2018-12 with java 11. How do we solve this?

Tags: java, eclipse, build.gradle

My byild.gradle file

Able to export jar with JAVA 8. when I configure to JAVA 11 exported jar doesn't contain external jars

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
    apply plugin: 'java-library'

```
// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations 
    { 
        all*.exclude group: 'org.slf4j', module: 'slf4j-log4j12' //by both name and group
    }

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile group: 'com.microsoft', name: 'sqljdbc4', version: '3.0'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '8.0.15'
    compile group: 'com.ibatis', name: 'ibatis2-common', version: '2.1.7.597'
    compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-io', version: '1.3.2'
    compile group: 'org.yaml', name: 'snakeyaml', version: '1.21'
    compile group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20171018'

    compile group: 'com.itextpdf', name: 'itextpdf', version: '5.5.13'
    compile group: 'com.itextpdf.tool', name: 'xmlworker', version: '5.5.13'  
    testCompile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-simple', version: '1.6.2'
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how to reproduce the issue? What do you mean by _"with Java 11"_? Eclipse running on Java 11, a Java project requiring Java 11, a JPMS-based project, ...?

Comment: @howlger, Java project with java 11, Export runnable jar through eclipse. It's not including external jars. Reconfigure same project to java 8  Export runnable jar it includes external jars.

Comment: Does this only happen with your project, or have you tested it with a "Hello World" example with both, an external JAR and a non-external JAR? If yes, what are the results and where is the bug report?

Comment: @howlger, It's working with Hello world project.. Problem with my specific Gradle project. I will be adding my build.gradle file to question.

Comment: Can you narrow it down any further? Does exporting runnable JAR generally not work with Gradle? Is it related to a specific JAR (maybe a [multi-release JAR](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238) or a required native library not included in the JAR)?

Comment: All the dependency jars(mentioned in build.gradle) not exporting to runnable jar when I use java 11 but  same works for java 8. I am not getting where is the problem. 1.Problem in Java 11?  2.When I use java 11 is there anything I need to add in build.gradle? 3.Is eclipse not supporting to include dependencies when I use java 11?

Comment: I am facing same issue... any update on this ?

Answer (score 0):

add this below lines into your build.gradle

```
jar { manifest {attributes "Main-Class": "your main class" } from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory()? it : zipTree(it) } }
```

then do a clean/build, 
the jar created in \build\libs folder is your runnable jar